# 2-step linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares

Very simple problem:

- First model: I run a linear regression of $Y$ on $X$ and $Z$.
- Second model: I regress $Y$ on $X$ only, compute the residuals, and regress these residuals on $Z$.

Why do I obtain a different coefficient for $Z$ in these two models?

Comment: Why shouldn't you get different coefficients..?

Comment: In both cases, I investigate the impact of $Z$ on $Y$ while controlling for the effect of $X$. That's why I thought that maybe we could get the same coefficient for $Z$ in both models. I imagine that using two steps in the second model is the reason why I don't get the same coefficient, but I'm not sure to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making change to make 9 cents, where you have nickles (worth 5 cents) and pennies (worth 1 cent).

**Case 1:** You consider using both nickels and pennies.  You make change of one nickel plus four pennies, using five total coins.  This is the most efficient solution.

**Case 2:** You first make as much change as possible using pennies, so use nine pennies.  Then you calculate how much is leftover to make (zero cents) and use zero nickels to make up this "residual".

Notice how considering all the available resources together leads to a better solution, this is what is going on in your linear regression example.  You're trying to minimize the mean squared error by choosing the coefficients, and you often do better by considering all the options at the same time than considering one resource at a time.